# What does 시원치 않다 mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, idiom

In the following sentence:

> 그런데 그렇게 주인공으로 세워 놓고도 팬들의 대접은 **시원치 않은** 경우가 많다. 각자 자기의 노래를 찾느라 부산하기 때문이다. 여기서는 오로지 노래 실력만이 중요하다.

(Source: 대학 강의 수강을 위한 한국어 읽기 중급2 P.66)

There is no entry in any of my dictionaries for the word 시원치 않다. When I tried typing in 시원치 on Google search there was a candidate with 않다, though the search result does not get anything relevant. At least now I feel like it is an idiom.

So what does this mean in this sentence?

Comment: You can still consult the [dictionary](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=71281) because 시원치 않다 is a contraction of 시원하지 않다.

Comment: @Klmo Are they synonyms? Is there such a rule that you can replace ~지 않다 with 치 or is this an exception?

Comment: There are the rules for such contractions: You can write -하지 as -치 (ㅏ is omitted and ㅎ + ㅈ becomes ㅊ) when it follows a voiced sound, and -하지 as -지 (하 is omitted) when it follows a voiceless sound. Voiced sounds in Korean are ㄴ, ㄹ, ㅁ, ㅇ and vowels.

Comment: @Klmo I reached B2 in Korean and I did't know this rule! Thanks. Maybe could you write it in your answer? I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means 시원하지 않다. 시원치 is just a contraction for 시원하지.

I would encourage you to skim 한글 맞춤법 when you have time. [한글 맞춤법](http://kornorms.korean.go.kr/regltn/regltnView.do) 제40항 해설 explains the contraction rules regarding the last syllable 하 of the *stem*:

> 어간의 끝음절 ‘하’가 줄어들면 줄어드는 대로 적을 것을 규정하고 있다. ‘간편하게’가 [간편케]가 되면 ‘간편케’로 적는다. 그런데 **어간의 끝음절 ‘하’가 줄어드는 방식은 두 가지**이다.
>
> 첫째, ‘하’가 통째로 줄지 않고 ‘ㅎ’이 남아 뒤에 오는 말의 첫소리와 어울려 거센소리가 되는 경우다. 이럴 때는 소리 나는 대로 적는다.
>
> ...
>
> 둘째, ‘하’가 통째로 줄어드는 경우다. 이때도 소리 나는 대로 적는다.
>
> ...
>
> **‘하’가 줄어드는 기준은 ‘하’ 앞에 오는 받침의 소리**이다. ‘하’ 앞의 받침의 소리가 [ㄱ, ㄷ, ㅂ]이면 ‘하’가 통째로 줄고 그 외의 경우에는 ‘ㅎ’이 남는다.
>
> ...

which can be summarized as the following:

> When the syllable 하 ends the stem of a verb or adjective,
>
> - you can remove ㅏ from "a voiced sound (ㄴ, ㅁ, ㅇ, ㄹ, or a vowel) + 하 + a basic voiceless sound (ㄱ, ㄷ, or ㅈ)," but the remaining ㅎ and the voiceless sound that follows it are combined into the corresponding aspirated sound (ㅋ, ㅌ, or ㅊ).
> - you can remove the entire 하 from "a voiceless sound + 하 + a basic voiceless sound" (but the latter voiceless sound will be pronounced as the corresponding tense sound (ㄲ, ㄸ, or ㅉ)).

This usage is not limited to -하지 (but **please note that there are *some exceptions***). Here are some other examples:

> - 단언하건대 = 단언컨대
> - 생각하건대 = 생각건대
> - 추진하고자 = 추진코자
> - 생각하고자 = 생각고자

There are a lot more examples in 한글 맞춤법.

Answer (score 2):

시원치 않다 is an idiom, meaning "not satisfactory" or "lukewarm" (as in attitude, reception, appearance, etc.).

(시원하다 means "cool/refreshing", so you can kind of see why 시원치 않다 has that meaning - imagine you ordered a glass of soda and it's lukewarm.)

Also, since it's an idiom, I think it's mostly written as 시원치 않다, or even 시원찮다 - 시원하지 않다 would be more likely used for the literal meaning.  E.g.,

> 저는 시원하지 않은 주스도 괜찮아요. (O) = I'm OK with juice that's not cold.
>
> 저는 시원치 않은 주스도 괜찮아요. (??? sounds weird to me)
>
> 주스가 맛이 시원찮다. (O) = This juice tastes so-so.
>
> 주스가 맛이 시원하지 않다. (O) = This juice doesn't have a refreshing/cool taste.